# How can I provide Sphinx documentation for a namedtuple (with autodoc)?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am trying to document a Python project with Sphinx, but I'm having trouble combining the `autodoc` extension with a `namedtuple` generated class.

In one document, `gammatone.rst`, I have:

```
:mod:`gammatone` -- gammatone filterbank toolkit
================================================

.. automodule:: gammatone
   :members:
.. automodule:: gammatone.coeffs
   :members:
```

In my `gammatone/coeffs.py`, I have:

```
from collections import namedtuple

ERBFilterCoeffs = namedtuple(
    'ERBFilterCoeffs', # Most parameters omitted
    [
        'A0',
        'gain',
    ])
```

The code generated by `namedtuple` includes very generic docstrings that Sphinx's `autodoc` module picks up and includes. I'd rather document the class properly myself, without forgoing `autodoc` for the rest of the module.

I've tried putting something like this just before the class:

```
"""
.. class:: ERBFilterCoeffs(A0, gain)
:param A0: A0 coefficient
:param gain: Gain coefficient

Magic coefficients.
"""
```

...but it doesn't show up in the generated docs. Putting it after the class results in it being nested underneath the generic class documentation, rather than replacing it.

How do I simply tell Sphinx (and the `autodoc` extension) to use my documentation for the `ERBFilterCoeffs` class instead of that generated by `namedtuple`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about after defining `ERBFilterCoeffs` with the namedtuple, try assigning that doc string to `ERBFilterCoeffs.__doc__`?

EDIT: Ok, how about this then:

```
class ERBFilterCoeffs(namedtuple('ERBFilterCoeffs','a b c')):
    """
    this is the doc string for ERBFilterCoeffs
    """
```

Comment: I get: `WARNING: autodoc can't import/find module 'gammatone.erb', it reported error: "attribute '__doc__' of 'type' objects is not writable", please check your spelling and sys.path` — so presumably I can't overwrite the docstring of the `namedtuple` generated type :/

Comment: As a side-effect, this will show itself as ``base`` which is a bit paradoxical... Other than that, the docs turn out fine :)

Answer (score 13):

You don't actually need to extend the namedtuple at all. You can put the docstring after the namedtuple.  This actually works for constants and attributes as well.

```
ERBFilterCoeffs = namedtuple('ERBFilterCoeffs', ['A0', 'gain', ])
""" Magic coefficients.

.. py:attribute:: A0

    The A0 attribute is something

.. py:attribute:: gain

    The gain attribute is blah blah

"""
```

Comment: In my case, "putting it after the class results in it being nested underneath the generic class documentation, rather than replacing it."

Comment: This won't work. Here you create a namedtuple assigned to variable `ERBFilterCoeffs` and then a define a multi-line string in vacuum.

Comment: @aconrad this is how sphinx documents constants, it works for sphinx, but maybe not for `ERBFilterCoeffs.__doc__`

Comment: You can leave out `:members:` in the `autoclass` directive. The only problem is that you can't rely on `:members:` to `automodule` in that case, and you have to list the module contents manually.

Comment: I tried this method, and it almost works for me, but it prefixes the attribute names with the name of the module. I can't use the global setting `add_module_names = False`, because I want them elsewhere. And I can't seem to annotate the `some_name` in `:py:attribute:: some_name` with tilde `~` or similar: the annotations are just included literally. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score -1):

In general, I prefer to have finer control over what is generated than adding a `:members:` directive to `automodule` gives. As such, I would recommend documenting `ERBFilterCoeffs` explicitly using `.. autoclass:: ERBFilterCoeffs`. I would not add a `:members:` directive here, since that will include the very generic default docs a `namedtuple` creates for each field. Instead, I would use `.. py:attribute:: ...`  elements in your docstring, which you can put before the class definition using the special `#:` comments:

```
#: Magic coefficients.
#:
#: .. py:attirbute:: A0
#:
#:    A0 coefficient
#:
#: .. py:attribute:: gain
#:
#:    Gain coefficient
ERBFilterCoeffs = namedtuple(
    'ERBFilterCoeffs', [# Most parameters omitted
        'A0',
        'gain',
    ]
)
```